# Searching for a string in a file with python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to do pretty much what a `'grep -i str file'` gives back but I have been hitting my head up against this issue for ages.

I have a func called 'siteLookup' that I am passing two parameters: str 's', and  file_handle 'f'.
I want to a) determine if there is a (single) occurrence of the string (in this example `site="XX001"`), 
and b) if found, take the line it was found in, and return another field value that I extract from that [found] line back to the caller.  (it is a 'csv' lookup).  I have had this working periodically but then it will stop working and I cannot see why.

I have tried all of the different 'open' options including f.readlines etc.

```
#example line: 'XX001,-1,10.1.1.1/30,By+Location/CC/City Name/'
#example from lookupFile.csv: "XX001","Charleston","United States"

sf = open('lookupFile.csv')

def siteLookup(s, f):
    site = s.split(',')[0].strip().upper()
    if len(site) == 5:
        f.seek(0)
        for line in f:
            if line.find(site)>=0:
                city = line.split(',')[1].strip('"').upper()
                return city
            # else site not found 
            return -1
    else:  # len(site) != 5
        return -1

city = siteLookup(line, sf)
print(city)
sf.close()
```

I am getting zero matches in this code. (I have simplified this example code to a single search).  I am expecting to get back the name of the city that matches a 5 digit site code - the site code is the first field in the example "line".

Any assistance **much appreciated**.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` is wrongly indented - if the thing you look for is not found in the first line, it will return -1 and not look further.

Use `with open(...) as f:` to make your code more secure:

with open("lookupFile.csv","w") as f:
    f.write("""#example from lookupFile.csv: 
"XX001","Charleston","United States"
""")

```
def siteLookup(s, f):
    site = s.split(',')[0].strip().upper()
    if len(site) == 5:
        f.seek(0)
        for line in f:
            if site in line:   # if site in line is easier for checking 
                city = line.split(',')[1].strip('"').upper()
                return city

        # wrongly indented - will return if site not in line
        # return -1

    # if too short or not found, return -1 - no need for 2 returns  
    return -1


line = 'XX001,-1,10.1.1.1/30,By+Location/CC/City Name/'

with open('lookupFile.csv') as sf:
    city = siteLookup(line, sf)
    print(city)
```

Output:

```
CHARLESTON
```

Comment: Thank you - tested & confirmed as working as desired!